# In HiveQL, how to select result for all rows and some rows and display them in one table?

Tags: hiveql

In HiveQL, how to select result for all rows and some rows and display them in one table?

For example i have country codes column, i want data for all World plus some few countries in one table.

I tried case when but closest i achieved was countries plus the rest of the world:

```
select
    case when lower(a.country) like 'cn' then 'China'
        when lower(a.country) like 'us' then 'USA'
        when lower(a.country) like 'uk' then 'UK'
        when lower(a.country) like 'de' then 'Germany'
        when lower(a.country) like 'jp' then 'Japan'
        when lower(a.country) like 'br' then 'Brazil'
    else "Rest"
    end as Country,
    c.D,
    avg(case when a.time between 1 and 999999 then a.time else NULL end) as avg_time,
    count(case when a.time between 1 and 999999 then a.time else NULL end) as time_count
from table1 a
    join table2 c on a.vdate=c.cdate
        and c.D like "2019_03"
group by c.D,
    case when lower(a.country) like 'cn' then 'China'
        when lower(a.country) like 'us' then 'USA'
        when lower(a.country) like 'uk' then 'UK'
        when lower(a.country) like 'de' then 'Germany'
        when lower(a.country) like 'jp' then 'Japan'
        when lower(a.country) like 'br' then 'Brazil'
    else "Rest"
```

I also tried to put `*` in `country` list below in another query but that gives error, naturally:

```
select 
    c.D, 
    a.B,
    avg(case when a.time between 1 and 999999 then a.time else NULL end) as 
    avg_time,
    count(case when a.time between 1 and 999999 then a.time else NULL end) as time_count
from table1 a
    join table2 c on a.vdate=c.date
where lower(a.country) in ("cn", "us", "uk", "de", "jp", "br")
    and c.D like "2019_03"
group by c.D, a.B
```

How can I pull all world and the six countries in one query?

Comment: can you provide us with schema of table1 and table2 and data sample?

Comment: table1    
country time      vdate    visitorid    beaconid
string bigint    string    string    string

table2 
date D
string int

sample for table1
visitorid beaconid country vdate       time
1         a1          us     2018-10-01  2917
2         a2          vn     2018-10-01  827
3         a3          us     2018-10-01  1377
4         a4          ca     2018-10-01  7470

sample table2
date                 D
2018-10-01 2018-03
2018-10-01 2018-03
2018-10-02 2018-04
2018-10-02 2018-04
2018-10-02 2018-04

not sure if i can paste files in comments